# Can DHCP server give out a lease time greater than requested by DHCP client?

Tags: linux, centos, dhcp

I have a centOS DHCP server configured to give out a lease of 20 mins. But a client is requesting a lease for 10 mins. Is it possible to configure dhcpd to give out a lease of 20 mins even if client requests for a 10 mins lease.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See dhcpd.conf(5):

```
   The min-lease-time statement

      min-lease-time time;

      Time should be the minimum length in seconds that will be assigned to a lease.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. DHCPD server will provide the Lease based on dhcpd options

```
min-lease-time 120; <- Mean minimum lease DHCP server will assign greater than 120 secs
max-lease-time 120; <- Mean maximum lease DHCP server will assign less than 120 secs
default-lease-time 120; <- Mean default lease DHCP server will assign is 120 secs
```

you want all 3 options for all the networks ranges you will setting up otherwise what happens client may get weird leases.

You can check man pages on linux server you have dhcpd configured

```
man 5 dhcpd
```

or check https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.conf